# a simple php updatable node

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

As best i can explain it..I have an html page with simple divs such as a 'news' section. Surrounded by divwrap,,etc.. I've seen several sites with full mysql/php with user login function, forums.The catch is the communities have an administration control panel where you have the ability to relocate nodes, add nodes or create a new article on the  page in consecutive order from the older posts..etc..all integrated in 1 with the power of mysql. I am aware of tutorials for simple community functions with user-login and such. I'd like to create a simple process from which an amateur user can login to the site and simple add articles,,very similar to a blog. Currently looking for suggestions i could search for ..maybe tutorials or perhaps a javascript alternate? Or perhaps the correct search syntax to use for scouring the web for tuts?

Comment: Why don't you use an existing CMS such as Joomla, Drupal, Wordpress, etc ?

Comment: Your question is too vague and open-ended. Can you narrow it down a bit?

Comment: @alfasin Already downloading Drupal.. Will find a way to implement this. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: @Dai i believe my issue is resolved, drupals fantastic.